# How can perform a task from superuser in django

Tags: django, django-views, decorator

I am trying to perform an action from superuser accept/reject the task, but after login from superuser it show the error. even if i logged in from non superuser if show the same error

```
  403 Forbidden
```

i am trying first time perform action from superuser i don't know how can i fix this issue

View.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class Approval(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    def test_func(self):
        if self.request.user == User.is_superuser:
           return True
        else:
           return False

    template_name = 'approve.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request):
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('approve',Approval.as_view(), name='approve')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if the user is a superuser with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class Approval(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'approve.html'
    
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'all_saloon': all_saloon})
```

The `all_saloon` is however strange: it means that if it is a list or `QuerySet` it will each time work with the *same* data, and thus if later a new `Saloon` is constructed, it will not take that into account.

You can alter the `handle_no_permission` function to determine what to do in case the test fails:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Approval(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'approve.html'
    
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
    
    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'all_saloon': all_saloon})
```

Likely you want to work with a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) instead.

Comment: How can i redirect the superuser to specific path?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: you can override the `handle_no_permission` to return a redirect, see edit.

Comment: Can you mention the documentation link or any other link where i can get the idea

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: see https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.mixins/UserPassesTestMixin/ this site shows the inheritance hierarchy of all views.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276496/how-can-add-the-data-in-db-field-which-already-exist