# How can add the data in db field which already exists

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to add the data in `main_storage` table but when I save the record it show the error

```
 failed unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'int'
```

In `Main_Storage` `productId` is foreign key I want to add the data according to the foreign key but it show the error

```
            try:
            data = self.request.POST.get
            orderView = GatePass(
                fault=data('fault'),
                remarks=data('remarks'),
                order_id=order_Id
            )
            dbItem = Order.objects.get(id=order_Id)
            items = dbItem.orderProduct.quantity
            order_request = OrderRequest.objects.get(pk=orderId)
            faultItem = orderView.fault
            if int(faultItem) >= items:
                return HttpResponse('error')
            else:
                order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity -= int(faultItem)
                Main_Storage.objects.filter(
                    product_id=productId
                ).update(
                    quantity=F('quantity') + order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity
                )
                order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity = int(faultItem)
                order_request.order.orderProduct.save()
                orderView.save()
```

Comment: `Main_Storage.quantity` does not make much sense, since that is not an *object* but the `Main_Storage` model.

Comment: i know but i don't know how can i add the data because i have already data in quantity.

Comment: Are you trying to get the quantity on the new object to be the sum of the quantity on all the objects in the table plus  the quantity from the order request?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: are we sure there is already a `Main_Storage` for that product id?

Comment: i want to sum the value of order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity in main_storage,quantity without creating new field

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  yes product_id is foreign key in Main_Storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the `Main_Storage` object with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Main_Storage.objects.filter(
    product_id=productId
).update(
    quantity=F('quantity') + order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity
)
```

This will work if we know that there is already *one* `Main_Storage` record for this `product_id`.

If we do not know that, we can work with [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
from django.db.models import F

qty = order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity

obj, created = Main_Storage.objects.get_or_create(
    product_id=productId,
    defaults={'quantity': qty}
)
if not created:
    obj.quantity = F('quantity') + qty
    obj.save()
```

Comment: first method worked now values has been sum in quantity but it takes not exact value for sum like if i give 100 it take take 90 for sum. How can i fix this issue

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: wat exactly is `order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity` are you sure that this is th amount to sum up?

Comment: order_request is table where order is foreign key same in order table orderProduct is foreign key through that key i get the quantity

Comment: i update the question i hope you can understand easily

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: can you share your modeling. I find it quite confusing, especially the fact that an `orderProduct` seems to have a quantity.

Comment: I have a question related to encryption decryption can u answer it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484357/how-can-set-the-boolean-value-in-django